# Add more array of objects into a localstorage key

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

I have a localstorage key '`st`' with value:

```
[{"id":"es","state":"5hwrte5"},{"id":"bs","state":"dakiei3"}]
```

**I want to add one more keyvalue at the end if it doesnt exist** so to end up with:

```
[{"id":"es","state":"5hwrte5"},{"id":"xs","state":"dakiei3"},{"id":"NEWKEY","state":"off"}]
```

So what I tried was:

```
if (typeof getstate(json, 'NEWKEY') == "undefined"){
  localStorage["st"] = JSON.stringify([{
     "id": "es",
     "state": getstate(json, "es")
  }, {
     "id": "xs",
     "state": getstate(json, "bs")
  }, {
     "id": "NEWKEY",
     "state": "off"
  }])
}
```

Where `getstate` gives me the state for a certain specific id.

Now the main issue is that I want to keep the values as their are (so i need to retrieve them at the time) and use the easiest method so **in case my key had 30 different id's and I wanted to add 1 more, I didnt had to retrieve values for all 30 id's.**

Comment: fyi, you can just test for `=== undefined` - no need to use `typeof` unless you are dealing with a possibly undefined variable (e.g. `typeof foo == 'undefined'` since `foo === undefined` would break in that case)

Comment: Just so you realize, JSON is a string format used to exchange javascript data.  Are you talking about an actual JSON string?  Or about a javascript array of objects?

Comment: @jfriend00 Changed the title. Im talking about a javascript array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you would be a lot better off with an object that uses each ID as a key, not an array of objects

```
var st={
  "es":{"state":"5hwrte5"},
  "xs":{"state":"dakiei3"}
}
```

Then to access data for an ID:

```
alert( st.es.state);
```

To add a new property:

```
st['newKey']={state:"off"}/* same as writing st.newKey={state:"off"}
     /* OR*/
st.newKey={state:"off"}
```

Object would then look like:

```
var st={
  "es":{"state":"5hwrte5"},
  "xs":{"state":"dakiei3"},
  newKey :{state:"off"}/* quotes on object keys are optional unless they contain special characters or spaces*/
}
```

You would then convert whole object to and from JSON using `JSON.stringify(st)` or `JSON.parse( localStorage['st'])`

**Edit:** if you prefer keeping array format you can add a new element as follows:

```
var st = [{"id":"es","state":"5hwrte5"},{"id":"bs","state":"dakiei3"}];

st.push( {"id":"NEWKEY","state":"off"})

/* results in */
[{"id":"es","state":"5hwrte5"},{"id":"xs","state":"dakiei3"},{"id":"NEWKEY","state":"off"}]
```

Using the array you would have to loop over each element in array to do a search for a specific ID

```
for(i=0 ; i< st.length; i++){
     var object= st[i];
    if ( object.id=="NEWKEY"){
           alert(object.state)
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont really see a difference between your answer and the solution im currently using. I am trying to avoid the last code bit which you need to set the value for each key, because if for an instance I had 30 different id's on a single row, I would had to give them all a value. I am trying to do something like: GET THE CURRENT WHOLE KEY as it is with its ids and values, and add 1 extra

Comment: OK ..adding one to array is easy using `push()` which is javascript array method. My thinking was when you need to access specific information by ID. In an array you have to loop over the whole array to look for the object with ID you want...or know the index position of it

Comment: I was kinda aware of the push regarding array approach but im not sure how i could pass it into the localstorage key st. Give me a sec

Comment: Because if I retrieve the key as var st = localStorage.getItem("st"); then I cant push into it

Comment: use `var st=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("st"))` to create javascript object/array from storage, then JSON.stringify to put it back